# AWS Lambda gives 400 error when deployed in prod

Tags: python, aws-lambda, http-status-code-400

I have a lambda function that sends notifications to slack based on S3 events. I configured and tested the function in a sandbox and it works, but when deployed to the production environment it gives me a 400 error. There is no VPC attached to the function and all configuration is the same in both setups. What can be the source for the error in the production environment?

Source code:

```py
    slack_message = {
        'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
        'text': message_body,
        'username': 'aws-lambda-bot',
        'icon_emoji': ':checkered_flag:'
    }

    req = Request(HOOK_URL)

    try:
        response = urlopen(req, data=json.dumps(slack_message).encode())
        logger.info(response)
        response.read()
        logger.info("Message posted to %s", slack_message['channel'])

    except HTTPError as e:
        logger.error("Request failed: %d %s", e.code, e.reason)

    except URLError as e:
        logger.error("Server connection failed: %s", e.reason)
```

Test results.

Sandbox:

[image]
Prod:
[image: AWS log prod]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're encoding your string? Also, a bad request usually means that one of the parameters provided is incorrect or missing. Are there any logs on the slack side?

Comment: Removing the decode did the trick. The original urllib2 function I modified used it and I maintained. I wonder why it wasn't a problem for the sandbox version of the same function. It works with the encode and sending to the same webhook.